# How can I create this multidimensional array from a foreach loop?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I cannot wrap my head around this...I have an array that looks like:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20120412
            [1] => United States
            [2] => Illinois
            [3] => Marion
            [4] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20120412
            [1] => United States
            [2] => Illinois
            [3] => Carbondale
            [4] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20120412
            [1] => United States
            [2] => Illinois
            [3] => Carbondale
            [4] => 2
        )
)
```

I am wanting it to be like:

```
array("United States" => array("Illinois" => array("Carbondale" => "4")));
```

So that it takes the Country out, Then the State, then adds together all of the city's numbers.

So far all I have is:

```
foreach($location_google_data3 as $location_google_data4){
    if($location_google_data4[0]==date("Ymd")){
         $today_visitsbycountry[$location_google_data4[1]]+=$location_google_data4[4];  
    }
}
```

This gives me an array with the country and number of visits so that I can iterate through it later, but not sure how to proceed with the rest.

Comment: If you don't need the date value, I suggest you remove it first. Also what have you done so far? Post your code please otherwise do your homework first.

Comment: Sorry, I have added what code that I have...I can also change the index to get the state or city array, but just not sure how to piece it altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this...

```
$result=array();
foreach ($a as $item)
    $result[$item[1]][$item[2]][$item[3]]+=$item[4];
```

Comment: This is probably solvable, pretty easily, but `++` won't work, as it doesn't just need an incrementor, it needs to be incremented by the value in the array.

Comment: Instead of `= 0`, it should be `= $item[4]`, and instead of `++` it should be `+= $item[4]`. The result should not be initialized to 0 because it begins with an initial value.

Comment: Yes, these changes have been made.

Comment: Im not really sure what you want. it would have worked in just about any form I had on here. Vote, don't vote, thats fine :)

Comment: Holy cow...love the activity, thanks everyone...marking Dutchie432's original answer...as I modified it and got it to work before I had the chance to come back.  I used:

`$result[$item[1]][$item[2]][$item[3]]+=$item[4];`

Thanks very much!

Comment: this will give you warnings of unset array items. I opted for aliasing in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10147228/367456).

Comment: Yes, there are better ways of doing everything. This is a demonstration, and will yield the correct result. Some warnings are more serious that others.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it (assuming your array is called `$input`):

```
$output = array();

foreach ($input as $city) {
    if (!isset($output[$city[1]])) {
        $output[$city[1]] = array();
    }

    if (!isset($output[$city[1]][$city[2]])) {
        $output[$city[1]][$city[2]] = array();
    }

    if (isset($output[$city[1]][$city[2]][$city[3]])) {
        $output[$city[1]][$city[2]][$city[3]] += $city[4];
    } else {
        $output[$city[1]][$city[2]][$city[3]] = $city[4];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$resultArray = array();
foreach($yourArray as $data)
{
    if(!isset($resultArray[$data[1]])) {
        $resultArray[$data[1]] = array();
    }

    if(!isset($resultArray[$data[1]][$data[2]])) {
        $resultArray[$data[1]][$data[2]] = array();
    }

    if(!isset($resultArray[$data[1]][$data[2]][$data[3]])) {
        $resultArray[$data[1]][$data[2]][$data[3]] = 0;
    }

    $resultArray[$data[1]][$data[2]][$data[3]] += $data[4];
}
```

Comment: Should be initialized to `$data[4]`, not 0.

Comment: Not if he is adding `$data[4]` on the next line, regardless.

Comment: @sberry That is true. I take it back. :)

Comment: too much work. PHP handles array access on the fly, you don't need to check for each index, you can `isset` check for the whole index at once.

Answer (score 1):

You do this by picking the values from the array, use them as keys for the new array and then add the number. This example uses a variable alias (reference), so the long version of the variable needs only written once:

```
$filterDate = '20120412';
$build = array();
foreach ($array as $item)
{
    list($date, $country, $state, $city, $number) = $item;
    if ($date != $filterDate) continue;
    $alias = &$build[$country][$state][$city];
    $alias += $number;
}
unset($alias);
```

Outcome (`$build`):

```
array(1) {
  ["United States"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Illinois"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Marion"]=>
      int(2)
      ["Carbondale"]=>
      int(4)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work, if not - something like this will do the trick:

```
$result = array();
foreach( $your_array as $arr ) {
    if( !isset( $result[ $arr[1] ] ) ) {
        $result[ $arr[1] ] = array();
    }
    if( !isset( $result[ $arr[1] ][ $arr[2] ] ) ) {
        $result[ $arr[1] ][ $arr[2] ] = array();
    }
    if( !isset( $result[ $arr[1] ][ $arr[2] ][ $arr[3] ] ) ) {
        $result[ $arr[1] ][ $arr[2] ][ $arr[3] ] = 0;
    }
    $result[ $arr[1] ][ $arr[2] ][ $arr[3] ] += (int)$arr[4];
}
```